# Container not expanding to cover floated elements

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

I have some floated elements and the container height is set to be at minimum the size of the viewport (min-height: 100vh), overflow: hidden.

However, in a responsive view (480x320) I find that the div is not expanding to contain the div which is holding the floated items. Therefore, the floated elements are cutting out of the div altogether as such:

[image]

I have tried adding the clearfix but this does not work.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="clients" id="clients">

        <h2 class>Clients</h2>

            <div class="clientLogoContainer">
                <div class="clientLogo">
                    <img src="assets/ethiopian.jpg" class="fullSizeLogo">
                </div>
                <div class="clientLogo">
                    <img src="assets/kenya.jpg" class="fullSizeLogo">
                </div>
                <div class="clientLogo">
                    <img src="assets/southafrican.jpg" class="fullSizeLogo">
                </div>
                <div class="clientLogo">
                    <img src="assets/qatar.jpg" class="fullSizeLogo">
                </div>
                <div class="clientLogo">
                    <img src="assets/coalindia.jpg" class="fullSizeLogo">
                </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
.clientLogoContainer {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;                 /* move the div's top border to the half height of the outer div*/
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* move the inner div up by half its height */
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.clearfix { /* used for the navigation bar to prevent li items from crashing into same line as the logo */
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Non-responsive view**
[image]

Comment: Is there a link so we can check adn edit the page to see how to fix it?

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot of unresponsive view, so we can see what you're trying to accomplish. Also, please provide a [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Non-responsive view added. The code is quite long, you want the whole CSS file?